# Write on GCP Datastore from GCP Cloud Function redirects to unwanted sign-in prompt

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-datastore, service-accounts

**Context:**

I want to write to **GCP Datastore** from within my Python **Cloud function**:

```
from google.cloud import datastore

def cloud_function_entry():
    client = datastore.Client.from_service_account_json("XXX.json")
    key = client.key("my-datastore-entity-kind")
    task = datastore.Entity(key)
    task.update({"description": description, "done": False})
    client.put(task)
    return "OK"
```

`XXX.json` is a service-account keyfile with the Datastore user role.

Locally, it works perfectly fine.

**Problem:**

When I deploy the function and trigger the HTTP endpoint, **I get redirected to an __unwanted__ Sign in page** under URL `https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fappengine.google.com%2F_ah%2Fconflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fus-central1-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net%2FMY_FUNCTION&hl=en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin` [image].

**Tried so far:**

- Getting service account credentials from ENV / GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
- Attaching the service account to the cloud function in cloud console.

**Resulted in:**

The same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to correctly setup the service account assigned to your Cloud Function and to not specify the service account within your code.

Change your code:

```
client = datastore.Client.from_service_account_json("XXX.json")
```

To this:

```
client = datastore.Client()
```

Next set up the service account used by your Cloud function.

Go to the Google Cloud Console -> Cloud Functions. Click on your function name. In the Function details page, scroll down to the "Service account". Make note of the service account email address. Click on the service account email address. This takes you to the IAM page for your Service Accounts.

In the left panel go to IAM. Find the service account on the list. Click the pencil icon located on the right-hand side. Make sure that you have a role attached to allow Datasore writes such as `roles/datastore.user` (Cloud Datastore User).

Once you have the correct IAM roles assigned to the service account, your Cloud Function will now be able to access Cloud Datastore using the service account's credentials. This is called ADC (Application Default Credentials). No need to specify the service account in your code, include the service account JSON key file, set environment variables, etc.

Note: You might need to do a few more things like setting the region when creating the datastore client in your code, using the correct client library for Datastore versus Datastore in Firestore mode.

Comment: Thanks for answering this in detail with very valuable information. I just upvoted your answer. :) However, in my case it was a typo in my endpoint URL. I will answer myself and mark it as correct answer, because I cannot be sure that my described behavior (unwanted redirect to sign-in) would also appear with permissions problems.

Comment: @JonasKemper Follow my answer and set up your credentials in a secure manner. I do not recommend specifying and including the JSON credentials in your app unless you are running your code outside of GCP.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was not with permissions/service accounts, but I had a typo in a function HTTP URL/path. When I tested locally with flask, the URL was correct: `host/create`. But deployed on GCP it needs to be `host/function-name/create`.